# Shell - base64 - decode - invalid option -- 'o' output

Tags: bash, shell, base64, sh, decode

-o (output) option is removed from base64.
i am getting the following error

```
$echo "sfsfsgsfsfs" | base64 --decode -o /tmp/sfsfsf.txt
base64: invalid option -- 'o'
```

it is inside a jar file, i can not change this code and rebuild it.
So i am try to find any alternatives

Comment: The GNU version, at least, of `base64` [doesn't appear to have a `-o` option](https://linux.die.net/man/1/base64). Do you think you should have a different version?

Answer (score 3):

Just redirect instead:

```
echo "sfsfsgsfsfs" | base64 --decode > /tmp/sfsfsf.txt
```

Comment: But  it is inside a jar file, i can not change this code and rebuild it. 
So i am try to find any alternatives